# How can I sum up functions that are made of elements of the imported dataset?

Tags: import, sum, wolfram-mathematica

See the code and error. I have already tried Do, For,...and it is not working.

CODE + Error from Mathematica:
Import of survival probabilities _{k}p_x and _{k}p_y (calculated in excel)

```
px = Import["C:\Users\Eva\Desktop\kpx.xlsx"];
px = Flatten[Take[px, All], 1];
```

NOTE: The probability _{k}p_x can be found on the position px[[k+2, x -16]

```
i = 0.04;

v = 1/(1 + i);

JointLifeIndep[x_, y_, n_] =   Sum[v^k*px[[k + 2, x - 16]]*py[[k + 2, y - 16]], {k , 0, n - 1}]

Part::pkspec1: The expression 2+k cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression 2+k cannot be used as a part specification.

Part::pkspec1: The expression 2+k cannot be used as a part specification.

General::stop: Further output of Part::pkspec1 will be suppressed during this calculation.

Part of dataset (left corner of the dataset):
k\x 18  19  20
0   1   1   1
1   0.999478086278185   0.999363078716059   0.99927911905056
2   0.998841497412202   0.998642656911039   0.99858030519133
3   0.998121451605207   0.99794428814123    0.99788275311401
4   0.997423447323642   0.997247180349674   0.997174407432264
5   0.996726703362208   0.996539285828369   0.996437857252448
6   0.996019178300768   0.995803204773039   0.99563600297737
7   0.995283481416241   0.995001861216016   0.994823584922968
8   0.994482556091416   0.994189960607964   0.99405569519175
9   0.993671079225432   0.99342255996206    0.993339856748282
10  0.992904079096455   0.992707177451333   0.992611817294026
11  0.992189069953677   0.9919796017009 0.991832027835091
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without having the exact same data files to work with it is often easy for each of us to make mistakes that the other cannot reproduce or understand.

From your snapshot of your data set I used Export in Mathematica to try to reproduce your .xlsx file. Then I tried the following

```
px = Import["kpx.xlsx"];
px = Flatten[Take[px, All], 1];
py = px; (* fake some py data *)
i = 0.04;
v = 1/(1 + i);
JointLifeIndep[x_, y_, n_] := Sum[v^k*px[[k+2,x-16]]*py[[k+2,y-16]], {k,0,n-1}];
JointLifeIndep[17, 17, 12]
```

and it displays `362.402`

Notice I used := instead of = in my definition of JointLifeIndep. := and = do different things in Mathematica. = will immediately evaluate the right hand side of that definition. This is possibly the reason that you are getting the error that you do.

You should also be careful with your subscript values and make sure that every subscript is between 1 and the number of rows (or columns) in your matrix.

So see if you can try this example with an Excel sheet containing only the snapshot of data that you showed and see if you get the same result that I do.

Hopefully that will be enough for you to make progress.